# Sorting events by event date - how?

Tags: php, date, sorting

I have at table where I store all events. In that table I have a column named "event_date". The person who creates a event has to type the date like this:d/m/Y - example: 27/02/2013.

But when I try to sort the results by the event_date ASC, it doesn't come out in the desired order. I have even tried ordering it with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date), but it doesn't solve my problem either.

How can I fix this?

There is one solution; when a person creates an event, I can convert it to a timestamp. But isn't it possible to sort it correctly as it is now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what data type is your "event_date" column?

Comment: While you can convert the dates to timestamps before sorting, you would be much better off to store the dates in a database field of type date or timestamp and use database `order by` to do the sorting for you.

Comment: @Raad The type is VARCHAR()

Comment: it should be Date type

Comment: @AleksG I have realised that now. But I actually thought that when I put ORDER BY event_date - mySQL would sort it correctly by itself. It i is my mind common sense that this order should be outputtet (example):
27/02/2013
01/03/2013
06/03/2013
etc..

Comment: @sanj If I use the type Date, can I still create the date like this: day/month/year, or should I convert it as the standard: year-month-day?

Comment: I don't see the problem with saving date like y-m-d, you can easily convert it into d/m/y in mysql when you select, try DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: It's no problem, i'll just convert it when outputting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to store your dates as YYYY/MM/DD in your VARCHAR column to have an alphanumeric sort work properly.
As it is, the system will sort:

```
27/02/2013
01/03/2013
06/03/2013
```

like this:

```
01/03/2013
06/03/2013
27/02/2013
```

If you can change your column to the DATE data type, you can either switch your input format to `YYYY-MM-DD` or continue to accept `DD/MM/YYYY` and use:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2013','%d/%m/%Y')
```

to convert the value to a valid date